# ElasticSearch - Query to match any part of path (path_hierarchy tokenizer)

Tags: elasticsearch

Apologies if this is an easy one but I wasn't able to come up with a query myself or find an answer online.

If I have a field 'category' in my elasticsearch index that uses the path_hierarchy tokenizer to store the taxonomy structure, is there a way to query and match on ANY word in that path?

```
PUT /stuff
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "categories": { 
          "tokenizer": "path_hierarchy"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /stuff/_mapping/item
{
  "properties": {
    "name": { 
      "type":  "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "category": { 
      "type":  "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "fields": {
        "tree": { 
          "type":     "string",
          "analyzer": "categories"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then I put in a couple of items:

```
PUT /stuff/item/1 {"name": "The Killer Books", "category": "Entertainment/Movie/Horror"}
PUT /stuff/item/2 {"name": "The Adventure", "category": "Entertainment/Books And Stories/Fantasy"}
```

Then I have a user search for 'Books'. It's just free form text, and I don't have any additional parameters that could help pinpoint the category. I want to get the movie titled "The Killer Books", but then also get the document under "Entertainment/Books And Stories".

If a user searches for just 'Stories', I also want to return the second document.

The problem I have is, I can't easily tell from just the search term alone where in the path structure the term might fall in. Is there a way to properly query this? I've tried queries like the following with no success:

```
GET /stuff/item/_search
{
  "query":{
     "multi_match":{ 
        "query":"Books",
        "fields":["title", "category"]
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why are you using `path_hierarchy tokenizer`. For your given query to work, you could map your fields with `standard analyzer` like this

```
PUT /stuff/_mapping/item
{
  "properties": {
    "name": { 
      "type":  "string" <--- using default standard analyzer
    },
    "category": { 
      "type":  "string" <---- using default standard analyzer
      "fields": {
        "tree": { 
          "type":     "string",
          "analyzer": "categories"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now your query

```
GET /stuff/item/_search
    {
      "query":{
         "multi_match":{ 
            "query":"Books",
            "fields":["name", "category"]
          }
      }
    }
```

will give you both the documents. I removed `"index" : "not_analyzed"` becuase It will index the string as it is so *The Killer Books* will be indexed as it is but with `standard analyzer` it will generate three tokens *the, killer , books* and hence your query will work.

Make use of [analyze endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/indices-analyze.html) to see how your data is indexed and it will be easy to write queries.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Doh! Having "index": "not_analyzed" on the category field is what was screwing me up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: using path_hierarchy gives you the tree level aggregations see this https://amsterdam.luminis.eu/2016/06/21/faceted-search-with-elasticsearch/